# Can I wrap an object in Proxy and trap and use get trap to prevent "TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, get, es6-proxy

In `Javascript`, If I try to do this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.z.c.f.d = 'foo';

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined`

    at repl:1:7
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:240:29)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:442:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:282:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:631:8)
```

I don't want this error to be thrown.

Just create `z.c.f` and add `d` value inside there.

We have a legacy code.

Now I want to wrap this obj in a proxy and be able to trap its methods.

If property is undefined, create one object there, if a non-object value; overwrite it.

I implemented this method and I can simply use this method in Proxy's trap, maybe:

```
// setByString is not in Object.prototype. Only in my testObject
testObject.setByString('f.o.o', 1999); 
// this adds an f object and an o object inside, then an o value with 1999 to testObject. Merges deeply.
```

Here my `testObject` is expected to only have numbers, undefined, strings, objects.

The point is I can't do it with proxies.

They don't seem to have what I need.

Anyway is there a way to do it, if not possible with Proxies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with proxies you can do exactly what you are looking for:

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name){
        if(!(name in target))
            target[name] = new Proxy({}, handler);;
        return target[name];
    }
};

var p = new Proxy({}, handler);
```

Now, give it a try with:

```
p.a.b.c = 45;//no TypeError here !!!
```

Is it what you expected ?

Comment: When I use  `util.inspect(p, { depth: null, colors: true })`, I get:

`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at formatValue (util.js:423:37)
    at formatProperty (util.js:833:11)
    at formatValue (util.js:612:17)
    at formatProperty (util.js:833:11)
    at formatValue (util.js:612:17)
    at formatProperty (util.js:833:11)
    at formatValue (util.js:612:17)
    at formatProperty (util.js:833:11)
    at formatValue (util.js:612:17)
    at formatProperty (util.js:833:11)`

Comment: This is what I expect, exactly. But are there is a circularity-like problem here maybe. Also saying `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p)));` gives the same call stack error.

Comment: Don't try to JSONify a proxy !!! Maybe this function is what you are looking for to get back your object:

    `JSON.proxyToJSON = function(p) {
 let result = {};
     if (typeof p != "object") return p; 
     for (prop in p) {
      result[prop] = JSON.proxyToJSON(p[prop]);
     }
     return result;
    }`

Comment: Excellent so far. Now, can I change this handler to set, so I will set any property as I want and I will always be getting an object when I call this property. (Not required. If not possible, ignore) Example:

obj.a.b.c = 13; console.log(obj) // { a: { b: { c: 13 } } };

Comment: ... `obj.a.b.c = 13` is quite equivalent to `set(get(get(get(obj, a), b), c), 13)` ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var testObject = {};
setByString(testObject, 'f.o.o', 1999); 
console.log(testObject);

function setByString(obj, props, val) {
  var current = obj;
  props.split('.').forEach((prop, index, self) => {
    current[prop] = index !== self.length - 1 ? current[prop] || {} : val;
    current = current[prop];
  });
}
```

Comment: Can I do this without strings? Is this possible in Javascript with something like Proxies etc?